# How to disable Google's preventing of "suspicious" sign-ins?

Tags: google-account

Google frequently blocks genuine logins by me on different IP addresses claiming them to be "suspicious" attempts, locking me out unless I have my phone.

How can I disable this behaviour? My test on an account without a phone number suggests removing my phone number is insufficient. Though Google says "Alternative emails ... can also be used to reach you in case you get locked out." I have never seen Google do that.

Comment: Have you added an alternative email in your Google account?